# Cannot upload a file to Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code

When I comment the app.use(fileUpload) line, the breakpoint I have set on app.post gets called from the browser. But it runs into an error saying Exception has occurred: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filetoupload' of undefined

However, when the app.use(fileUpload) statement is uncommented, the breakpoint at app.post is not called at all.

So, not clear what is missing.

```
const express =require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

const app = express();


app.use(express.static('./public'));
app.use(fileUpload);

app.listen(9000,function() {

    console.log('My server is running on port 9000');
})

app.post('/sendFile', function(req, res) {
    let sampleFile = req.files.filetoupload;
    sampleFile.mv('./Uploads/FirstImage.jpg', function(err) {
    if (err)
        return res.status(500).send(err);
    res.send('File uploaded!');
    });
});
```

HTML Page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="description" content="Test File Upload">
      <meta name="keywords" content="Test File Upload">
    <meta name="author" content="This and That">
    <title>Welcome</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/sendFile" method="POST" name="SendDetails" onsubmit="return validateForm()">

    <section id="boxes">
        <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="environment" name='filetoupload' id="useCamera">
          <input class = 'buttons' type="submit" value="Submit photo" id='btnGoForIt' style="margin-left:30%">

    </section>
    <script src = 'home.js'></script>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

home.js contains the below validateForm() which is supposed to be triggered at the time of submit.

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["SendDetails"]["filetoupload"].value;
  if (x == "") {
    alert("No image found to send to Nodejs");
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. We can't see how you are making the request. Perhaps the problem is uploading the file, not reading the file from the request

Comment: Thanks for that. Will paste the HTML code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you take look at example of  [express-fileupload](https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload/tree/master/example)

I think it cause probably from encType tag or checking for files exist.

Comment: This also was required. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this `app.use(fileUpload({ useTempFiles: true }));`, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

add enctype='multipart/form-data' tag to form